# Why must this tf.placeholder be a float?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

Why does **x** needs to be a **float**? Why cant it be **int** since I am passing in a **list of type int**?

Code:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])  # Why must this be a float?
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, 2])

with tf.name_scope("network"):
    layer1 = tf.layers.dense(x, 100, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="hidden_layer")
    output = tf.layers.dense(layer1, 2, name="output_layer")

with tf.name_scope("loss"):
    xentropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=output)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy, name="loss")

with tf.name_scope("train"):
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
    training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

with tf.name_scope("eval"):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        for i in range(1, 50):
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            saver = tf.train.Saver()
            sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={x: np.array(train_data).reshape([-1, 1]), y: label})
            if i % 10 == 0:
                saver.save(sess, "saved_models/testing")
                print "Saved"
```

When I change it to tf.int32, it gives the following error:

```
TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'features' has DataType int32 not in list of allowed values: float16, float32, float64
```

I can provide more code if needed.

Comment: Inputs are given as `train_data = range(1, 10000, 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to [`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits):

> logits and labels must have the same shape [batch_size, num_classes] and the same dtype (either float16, float32, or float64).

I suppose you *could* compute a loss with integer inputs. However, most of the time, this loss is minimized by gradient descent -- as you do -- which means inputs needs to encode real numbers to get arbitrary updates.

The thing is that `tf.layers.dense` won't change the type of your input. So it will produce an integer output it its input is an integer. (At least if the activation is compatible with integers, such as `relu` -- a `sigmoid` would raise an error).

What you probably wanted to do is provide integer inputs *then* do all computations in say `tf.float32`. To do this, cast your input first before providing it to `dense`:

```
layer1 = tf.layers.dense(tf.to_float(x), 100, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="hidden_layer")
```